# What will happen if I connect a solar panel and batteries in parallel?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, solar-cell

What would happen if I connect a 9 V solar panel in parallel with a battery consisting of 6 x AA 2300 mAh NiMH at 7.2 V in series?

Panel:

Voc - 11.25 V
Vmp - 9 V
Isc - 0.41 A
Imp - 0.38 A
Wmp - 3.5 W

Battery:

6 x 2300- mAh NiMH cells

There will be a Schottky diode, of course.

It is said if you want to connect two power source of different voltages in parallel, both should be CC/CV? I'm not quite sure if the solar panel provides CC/CV. Please clarify.

Does it need any regulation?

My purpose is to provide for a 5V, 2A load using a buck converter.

Thank you.

Comment: You will eventually overcharge and destroy the batteries, that's what will happen.

Comment: You probably want to look at something like the LTC3130 (or along those lines) from linear technology. It has an application similar to what you want to do.

Comment: Do you mean 6 NiMH? 4 of them at 7.2V are already overcharged to the point of destruction.

Comment: My answer updated to match your added specs. I built solar powered products with NimH cells. Charge control is an annoying compromise in this application. LiIon are far easier to manage with variable charge rates.

Comment: You **STILL** have not provided enough information to allow an  answer with good probability of correctness. You say 5V 2A load. Why not tell us what the load actually is, whether it always draws 2A or if that is max or typical or average or octarine? Does it operate when the panel is operating or only at night or ? Is it LED, phone charger, motor, ...? Does it need 5V at say +/- 5% or tighter or much looser or ?? | If you want best efficiency from the panel then you may want TWO converters - panel to battery and battery to load. But, maybe not, but knowing the actual question will help.

Answer (score 3):

A PV (solar) panel acts as a good approximation to a constant current source when loaded to below its optimum voltage.

Updated:  With the added PV panel and battery specifications it can be seen that:

The panel will fully charge the battery in about mAh_battery / Imp
= 2300 mAh / 380 mA ~= 6 hours of full sun.
Sunshine hours (full sun at 1 kW/m^2) vary with location, season and weather conditions but typically varies from about 2 SSH in midwinter to 6 SSH in full summer. SSH for many locations worldwide can be found from [The fabulous Gaisma site](http://www.gaisma.com).
With 2 SSH/day it will take ~= 3 days to fully charge the battery, and with 6 SSH it will fully charge in 1 day.
As Voc is >> Vbattery and as the panel will deliver useful current above Vmp, then the panel will deliver ~= Imp into the fully charged cells and modern 2300 mAh cells with no readsorption of gas generated will rapidly be destroyed. A regulator is therefore needed.
As mentioned below, a clamp regulator set to about 8.7V will probably be acceptable. Current when fully charged should be checked and if necessary Vclamp may need to be adjusted. An alternative is to let Vbattery rise to somewhat above 8.7V indicating full charge and then cut off charging either until next day or until discharge is initiated.

NimH are usually regulated by detecting negative delta V at full charge or delta battery temperature rate or absolute battery temperature but none of these are reliable in most solar applications due to variable charge rate with insolation and solar heating. Absolute temperature from charging and solar heating combined is a good indication that charging should be stopped but not that charging is complete if solar heating is significant.

---

Older:

NimH cells need about 1.45V each for full charge at current well below C (eg well below 2A for 2000 mAh cells. This voltage varies somewhat by cell brand and model but 1.45V is a good starting point.
So 4 cells need 4 x 1.45 = 5.8V for full charge (before Schottky diodes is allowed for) and
6 cells need 6 x 1.45V = 8.7V.

So - a panel rated at 9V Vmp (voltage at maximum power) may not treat 6 x NimH too badly but will continue to charge 4 x NimH cells at nearly full panel current even when the cells are fully charged. So whether you have 4 or 6 cells matters - and panel Imp mA and  battery mAh also matter.

Older NimH with say <= about 1800 mAh for an AA cell could be trickle charged at <= C/10 indefinitely. More modern cells of >=2000 mAh capacity for AA MUST NOT be trickle charged after full charge state is reached. While older cells had gas recombination systems to recombine Hydrogen and Oxygen generated by electrolysis, these systems are not included in higher capacity cells (as the room is used for additional active battery materials. Trickle charging higher capacity cells will dry them out rapidly and lead to early failure.

If a PV panel is liable to frequently fully charge NimH cells then overcharging can be prevented by adding a "clamp" or shunt regulator set to 1.45V/cell. For very low capacity panels a TL431 adjustable active zener( clamp regulator) can be used directly  for PV panels with more mA output than a TL431 can handle can use a shunt transistor driven by a TL431.  A conventional zener has far too soft a V-I "knee" to be used in this application.

It is also possible to use a series regulator but this needs care due to battery voltage drop when charge is removed.

Comment: Voc - 11.25 V, Vmp - 9 V, Isc - 0.41 A, Imp - 0.38 A, 6 NiMH batteries each at 2300 mAh

Comment: Peak power(Pmax) - 3.5 W

Comment: @royc I'd have undone the edit EXCEPT it was made by you :-0.

Comment: I had deleted my answer yours was much more detailed. Ref to me made no sense in that context.

Comment: Wouldn't a buck converter be better if I plan to change solar panel with different ratings? Or linear regulators are better at small current?

Comment: What should I add for it to stop charging when it reaches - delta V?

Comment: @Stannis Charging should be stopped at Vabsolute (about 8.7V as above). Any circuit that can prevent current from the panel charging the battery when Vbat is >= 8.7V will suffice. As Vbat will fall when Vcharge is removed you need either hysteresis or a circuit that holds Vchagre AT 8.7V. | Negative delta V occurs when a NimH cell is charged at CC (constant current). In a solar system Vchjarge can "wave around" with changes in solar insolation so a negative delta-V detector would be false-tripped too often in practice.

Comment: The [**LTC3130**](http://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=ltc3130) switching regulator is an extremely capable device that can do buck or buck boost or other conversion. It is overkill for this tak but could be ued BUT you still need to decide how to manage it. You can control Vpanel ~=  9V with a slight rise in panel voltage as current rises - this tends to optimise energy transfer (~~= MPPT). You still need to make end of charge decisions. | Worst case passive regulator or clamped panel is 6V/9V ....

Comment: ... ~= 66% efficient when battery is "flat" and about (8.7V+ 0.3V VSchottky) = 9V when battery is fully charged = 100% efficient. As best efficiency is wanted when Vbat is low a buck converter will help improve charge rate.

Comment: When there is a load, wouldn't the PV cells become the source. When a cloud passes by and PV cells' voltage drops below the voltage of the battery, doesn't the battery becomes the source?

Doesn't it bypass the battery?

Comment: Yes. And? The Schottky diode means the battery will not 'back feed' into the panel. Your question is about charging and running the load is not specifically mentioned. The PV panel can only supply the Wattage it can generate at a given moment and the battery must supply the balance if needed. The question is somewhat light on detail (this  is usually the case) BUT as Wpmax = 3.5W and as Wload max = 2A x 5V = 10W, then if converter load is ever above 35% of maximum the battery must make up the difference. BUT it is not obvious what the point of the question is.

Comment: I thought the buck converter would turn up the current while turning down the voltage. How do you even calculate the output current?

Comment: An MPPT converter - which is a buck converter designed to optimise energy transfer, will adjust the panel load so that it operates at optimum power output for give "insolation" (sunlight) levels  and then output the energy acquired into the load - with a loss of energy due to converter inefficiencies. So Panel operates at Wmp for the insolation level and output is Wmp x efficiency. Output current is then Power_out/Load_voltage. In full sunlight panel output is 3.5W so output of converter is 3.5W x say 90% ~~= 3.15W. Almost certainly less in practice....

Comment: ...  If output is say 3W then IF desired load voltage is 5V the converter can supply I = P/V = 3.0W/5V = 0.6A. If your 5V load needs more than 0.6A the balance MUST be provided by the battery - in this case if load is 2A then battery must provide 2.0-0.6A = 1.4A at 5V or equivalent energy if at panel potential.

Comment: The most useful answer needs the question to be more detailed than at present. There are too many uncertainties. See above. Nowadays PV panels are relatively low cost compared to other parts of the system and a better solution may be a larger panel rather than optimising panel to battery and battery to load energy transfer. Without more information the best approach is unknowable.